# How to visualize .data files?

Tags: data, python, binary

I am working with simulation models trying to carrying out some predictions in ocean waves and this stuff. (MITgcm)

I am able to run the program and generate hundreds of .data and .meta files, but i don't know how to visualize them.

I think it is possible to read and visualize it using Mathematica or Python, but i really don't know how to do it.

Documentation says:

"Each variable
is associated with two files with suffix names .data and .meta. The .data file contains the data written
in binary form (big endian by default). The .meta file is a “header” file that contains information about
the size and the structure of the .data file. This way of organizing the output is particularly useful when
running multi-processors calculations."

Comment: What is the format of your data? What are the desired visuals? I would encourage you to visit Mathematica documentation center. It is probably THE best documentation in the world. To start you off look at `Import` function and perhaps this link for vizualization: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataVisualization.html

Comment: Perhaps as importantly, could you give us a sample of the data you are analyzing in your question? What would you like Mathematica to do with your data? Simply "show" it somehow? Do further calculations and visualize those results?

Comment: According to [this](http://mitgcm.org/public/r2_manual/latest/online_documents/node100.html) the MITgcm .data files contain binary data. You can read them with `BinaryRead`, though you will need to understand the file format to interpret the data properly. According to that link there are matlab scripts included with MITgcm which read the output files. You could examine those scripts and write a *Mathematica* version.

Answer (score 3):

**Assumption**

A.1 - When loaded, data is in a form of `List` of `List` with a single entry in ea. nested `List`.

**Simple example:**

```
(*First import some arbitrary data*)
Flatten @ Import @ "C:\\Users\\-e\\Documents\\data.data"
```

**Output:**

```
{123421, 562341, 784234, 673477}
```

Function `Flatten` in the above example reduces the `List` of `List` data structure to `List` only.

```
(*Visualize data*)
ListPlot @ %
```

**Output:**

[image: simple output example]

**Reference:**

[@ % etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
[Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html)
[List](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html)

**Tutorials:**

[Import and Export Files](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingFiles.html)
[Data Visualization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataVisualization.html)
[List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)